# How to correctly use the add method in Java?

Tags: java, methods, addition, bluej

I need to add the Rectangle to the ArrayList called bricks as you can see below.

```
private void drawBrick(int startX, int startY){

    new Rectangle();

    currentColor = 0;

    startX = 54;
    startY = 16;

    bricks = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    bricks.add("Rectangle");


}
```

I keep getting compilation errors after adding that that last line of code and this weird warning pops up saying "Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output."

Anyone know what I've done wrong?

Comment: When you did `new Rectangle()`, you made a `Rectangle` object. Right now you're not actually doing anything with it though, you would store that in a variable then add it to your list.

Comment: You need to learn about basic Java syntax. You are trying to add a string with the contents `Rectangle` into the list, not a Rectangle object. You should assign your `new Rectangle()` to a variable and use that.

Comment: You added string "Rectangle". It was not Rectangle instance.

Comment: Where to start! One that hasn't been mentioned is that you'll overwrite your `ArrayList` `bricks` each time you call the method, making it useless.

Comment: You keep getting compilation errors **such as what**? Without that information there is no question here to answer. NB There are hundreds of `add()` methods in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just refer to the `Rectangle` you created by using `"Rectangle"`. Instead, you need to name the `Rectangle` when you create it and use that name later on, like this:

```
private void drawBrick(int startX, int startY) {
    Rectangle theRectangle = new Rectangle();

    currentColor = 0;

    startX = 54;
    startY = 16;

    bricks = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    bricks.add(theRectangle);
}
```

Notice how that creates a variable called `theRectangle` which is set equal to the `Rectangle` you create, then that specific `Rectangle` (`theRectangle`) is added to the `ArrayList` called `bricks`.